# Is "Michael here" correct?

Tags: grammar

Why Michael, [vsause](http://www.youtube.com/user/Vsauce)'s host at the start of each video says "Michael here" instead of "Michael is here"?

Is it grammatically correct or just a slang / simplified way of speaking?

Comment: Please define just what you mean by “grammatically correct” explicitly here.

Comment: By "grammatically correct" I mean, that there is a rule that you should say in this way. I learned that the verb is mandatory in the sentence but here it's absent.

Comment: I don’t know why you think all utterances must have a verb in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an abbreviation of 'Michael is here'; rather of 'This is Michael here': compare the BBC wartime introduction '*Ici Londres*'. This is a not uncommon way of introducing yourself, though it always sounds a little strange to me.

And 'grammatically correct' in your question also sounds slightly strange. No, this is not a complete sentence, but there is no reason why it should be; headlines, interjections, introductions and the like need to be understood rather than to be precise.